Generalisierte Relativsätze

Wem man die Hand gibt ,dem sollte man in die Augen sehen.

Kommt nach dem Verb "sehen* nicht Akkusativ d.h. soll da nicht den stehen?Ich habe diesen Satz aus einem Kursbuch.
Ist Wem man die Hand gibt den sollte man in die Augen schauen. nicht richtig?

Die Überschrift spricht den Relativsatz "wem..." an, die Frage geht dann aber über die Ergänzungen des Verbs im Hauptsatz, "sehen". Das Wort "den / dem" ersetzt im Hauptsatz  ja den Relativsatz, ab da wird er für die Frage nicht mehr gebraucht.

In der Tat, die Überschrift ist irreführend, der Kern der Frage hat nichts mit Relativsätzen zu tun.

Der Dativ erscheint zusammen mit der Präpositionalgruppe "in die Augen", die ist die eigentliche Ergänzung des Verbs. Es heißt hier nicht: "jemanden sehen", sondern die Konstruktion sagt, wohin man schaut: "in seine Augen sehen". Wenn ein Körperteil genannt wird, kann man den Besitzer des Körperteils, also die insgesamt betroffene Person, zusätzlich mit dem Dativ hinzufügen, diese beiden Ergänzungen müssen dann zusammen auftreten:

jemandem in die Augen sehen (in seine Augen)
jemandem auf den Kopf schlagen (auf seinen Kopf)
jemandem auf den Fuß treten (auf seinen Fuß)
etc.

PS: Äußerlich ähnlich ist vielleicht "jemandem die Hand geben" - das ist natürlich ein anderer Fall! Das Verb "geben" hat von sich aus eine Dativ-Ergänzung (anders als "sehen" oder "treten"), und es ist ja auch die Hand des Subjekts, nicht die der Zielperson.

Mit "schlagen" geht allerdings auch der der Akkusativ.

Was der Satz eigentlich ausdrücken soll, ist: Wem man die Hand gibt, in dessen Augen soll man schauen.
D.h. die Augen, in die man schauen soll, sind die Augen desjenigen, dem man die Hand gibt. Wenn es um die Zugehörigkeit von Körperteilen geht, wird das aber im Deutschen oft mit dem Dativ ausgedrückt. Mit dem Akkusativ ist das nicht möglich.
Diese Art von Sätzen sind Thema in dieser Frage: Most German sentence construction: "I will throw a snowball in your face"
